# How to setup Doctrine 2.1.x and Zend Framework 1 with Bisna

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework

I am trying to setup my environment to make Doctrine 2.1 + ZF 1 work together.  My take is try to use Bisna but I could not find info about setting the download packages for ORM/DBAL in the /library folder of my app.

What should I put there? (the entire tar.gz from doctrine-orm/doctrine-dbal?)

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bisna's configuration is agnostic about where Doctrine has been installed in your environment. It doesn't actually need to be in your /library. What Bisna does expect, is that your /path/to/Doctrine/ folder has the following structure:

```
/path/to/Doctrine/ORM
/path/to/Doctrine/DBAL
/path/to/Doctrine/Common
```

I generally keep Doctrine in /usr/share/php/Doctrine, and tell Bisna where to find it by adding this line to the application.ini

```
resources.doctrine.includePath = "/usr/share/php/Doctrine"
```

If Doctrine is in your application's library, then your configuration might look something like this:

resources.doctrine.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Doctrine"

Comment: Hi, I'll check that.   In my case I need to have all libraries in the project since I can't control if the hosting server will have that on a system-wide-path.  I'll probably add to the library.   One a side question where the models (which will use the Doctrine2 annotation) should go?  Under the standard /models?

Comment: Well, it did not work.  The application.ini from bisna contains a lot  of settings.  I had to edit it because it refers to ../library/vendor/doctrine... and edit the Bootstrap.php  public function _initAutoloaderNamespaces()
    {
        require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

        $autoloader = \Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $fmmAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Bisna');
        $autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($fmmAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Bisna');
    }

Comment: The problem was in the path.   After carefully reading all entries in the application.ini I've managed to get the right combination.

Answer (score 1):

```
Look for MyNamespace and replace with yours.
The .ini assumes that the doctrine and symfiny libraries are located under library folder.

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine Class Loader Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaderClass = "Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaderFile  = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_common.namespace   = "Doctrine\Common"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_common.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_dbal.namespace   = "Doctrine\DBAL"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_dbal.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_orm.namespace   = "Doctrine\ORM"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_orm.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.symfony_console.namespace   = "Symfony\Component\Console"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.symfony_console.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Doctrine"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.symfony_yaml.namespace   = "Symfony\Component\Yaml"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.symfony_yaml.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Doctrine"

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine Cache Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default cache instance to be used. Optional is only one cache is defined
resources.doctrine.cache.defaultCacheInstance = default

; Cache Instance configuration for "default" cache
;resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.id = default
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.adapterClass = "Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache"
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.namespace    = "MyNamespace_"
;resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.host = localhost
;resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.port = 11211
;resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.persistent    = true
;resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.weight        = 1
;resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.timeout       = 1
;resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.retryInterval = 15
;resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.status        = true

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine DBAL Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default connection to be used. Optional if only one connection is defined
resources.doctrine.dbal.defaultConnection = default

; DBAL Connection configuration for "default" connection
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.id = default
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.eventManagerClass  = "Doctrine\Common\EventManager"
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.eventSubscribers[] = "DoctrineExtensions\Sluggable\SluggableSubscriber"
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.configurationClass = "Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration"
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.sqlLoggerClass     = "Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger"
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.types.my_type      = "Application\DBAL\Type\MyType"

; Database configuration
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.wrapperClass = ""
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.driver   = "pdo_mysql"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.dbname   = "dbname"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.host = "dbhosr"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.port = 3306
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.user = "dbuser"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.password = "dbpassword"
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.driverOptions.ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERIES = true

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine ORM Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default EntityManager to be used. Optional if only one EntityManager is defined
resources.doctrine.orm.defaultEntityManager = default

; EntityManager configuration for "default" manager
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.id = default
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.entityManagerClass   = "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.configurationClass   = "Doctrine\ORM\Configuration"
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.entityNamespaces.app = "Application\Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.connection     = default
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.autoGenerateClasses = true
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.namespace           = "MyNamespace\Entity\Proxy"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.dir                 = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Argo/Entity/Proxy"
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataCache = default
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.queryCache    = default
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.resultCache   = default
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.DQLFunctions.numeric.PI = "DoctrineExtensions\ORM\Query\Functions\Numeric\PiFunction"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.annotationRegistry.annotationFiles[]     = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php"
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.annotationRegistry.annotationNamespaces.0.namespace   = "Gedmo"
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.annotationRegistry.annotationNamespaces.0.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/vendor"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.adapterClass          = "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.mappingNamespace      = "MyNamespace\Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.mappingDirs[]         = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/MyNamespace/Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.annotationReaderClass = "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.annotationReaderCache = default
;resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.annotationReaderNamespaces.App = "Application\DoctrineExtensions\ORM\Mapping"
```